# Isomorphic complex line bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I was wondering if there is a result which says that if I have two differentiable manifold that are diffeomorphic then their complex line bundle are isomorphic. For example there is an explicit diffeomorphism between the 2-sphere and the 1-dimensional projective complex space. The tautological line bundle over the 1-dimensional projective line bundle can be used also for The 2-dimensional sphere?

Comment: Which line bundles?Typically there are many nonisomorohic ones.

Comment: Complex line bundles, namely take $\{([z],\lambda) | \lambda \in mathbb{C}*}$ to be the tautological line bundle on $CP^1$. Since $CP^$diffeomorphic to $S^2$ can I use this complex line bundle on $S^2$?

Comment: Do you know about pull-back of bundles ?

Comment: I know what is a pull back of a vector bundle, why ?

Comment: If you know how pull back bundles you can use it to answer your question.

Comment: Could you add please more details?

Answer (score 4):

The pullback of bundles along the diffeomorphism gives you a bijection between bundles over the two manifolds.  Doesn't really matter what sort of bundles you're dealing with (line bundles,  sphere bundles,  etc.).

In fact,  it suffices that the manifolds are homotopy equivalent, since pullback of bundles only depends on the homotopy class of the map.

However,  note that in general the bijection depends on the homotopy class of the map,  so different homotopy classes give you different bijections. There is no canonical bijection.

Answer (score 2):

In your precise case, using clutching functions you can easily describe any line/vector bundle on $S^2$, see e.g [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) at the section "Clutching Functions" where this case is explicitly computed. This is also the way how you build vector bundle on $P^1$ after all, simply by gluing vector bundle on affine space.

Comment: A small remark : by definition pullback is functorial, i.e $(f \circ g)^* = g^* \circ f^*$ and $id^* = id$. In particular, if $f \circ g = id$ then $f^*$ is the right inverse of $g^*$ so pulling back gives isomorphism between isomorphism classe of vector bundles on $S^2$ and $\mathbb P^1$, and works with any diffeomorphism.